# how to make pod run on a specific path on EKS worker node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

Right now, my service is running on swagger/index.html.

I would like to make my pod run on abc/swagger/index.html.

I would like to use this path as part of my ingress like domain.com/abc/swagger/index.html. Right now, only domain.com/swagger/index.html is working.

Please advise how can I do that.

Thanks

Comment: share the ingress yaml

Comment: apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:x.x.x.x
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-01
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-01
spec:
  rules:
    - host: lb-dev.domain.com
      http:
     paths:
          - path: /vendor/*
            backend:
              serviceName: vendor-lb
              servicePort: 80

Comment: Service works when I put path: /* and browse with lb-dev.domain.com/swagger/index.html
but as soon as I put path as : /vendor/* and try to browse service with : lb-dev.domain.com/vendor/swagger/index.html, it does not turn up.

I'm using ALB ingress. please advice how can I make it work.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu

I have listed my ingress and query above. Kindly advise .

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your [ingress path](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource) from

```
http:
  paths:
  - path: /swagger/*
```

to

```
http:
  paths:
  - path: /abc/swagger/*
```

---

**OR**

---

Add another path like in this [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout)

Then it would work on both, /swagger and /abc/swagger

```
http:
  paths:
  - path: /swagger/*
    backend:
      serviceName: service
      servicePort: 8080
  - path: /abc/swagger/*
    backend:
      serviceName: service
      servicePort: 8080
```

---

More about ingress [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and specificaly on eks [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html).

**EDIT**

Based on the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html) those paths should work

```
Example path patterns

/img/*
```

> The path pattern is used to route requests but does not alter them. For example, if a rule has a path pattern of /img/*, the rule would forward a request for /img/picture.jpg to the specified target group as a request for /img/picture.jpg.

Could you try use it without`*`? So it would be /vendor/swagger/

Comment: Service works when I put path: /* and browse with lb-dev.domain.com/swagger/index.html but as soon as I put path as : /vendor/* and try to browse service with : lb-dev.domain.com/vendor/swagger/index.html, it does not turn up. I'm using ALB ingress. please advice how can I make it work

Comment: apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

kind: Ingress
  annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:x.x
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-01
     alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-01

spec:
 rules:
  -host: lb-dev.domain.com

  http:

 paths:
      - path: /vendor/*

        backend:

          serviceName: vendor-lb
          servicePort: 80